# What is the meaning of “es bedarf eines Aktes”?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

What is the meaning of the phrase “es bedarf eines Aktes”?

Context:

> Um sozusagen zum Kern dessen vorzustoßen „was da steht“, bedarf es eines
>   Aktes in unseren Köpfen.

Also, why is the genitive used here?

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] to learn more about it. Note that simple translation requests are off-topic. Please include the work you did yourself, how far you got and why you are stuck. (Especially note that your second question will probably be answered by every dictionary that lists usage.)

Answer (score 3):

Found here: http://gbi.ira.uka.de/vorlesungen/k-02-signale-skript.pdf

Quote:

> 2.2 ÜBERTRAGUNG UND SPEICHERUNG
>
> Schallwellen, Lichtwellen, usw. bieten die Möglichkeit, eine Mitteilung von einem Ort zu einem anderen zu übertragen. Damit verbunden ist (jedenfalls im alltäglichen Leben) immer auch das Vergehen von Zeit.
>   Es gibt eine weitere Möglichkeit, Mitteilungen von einem Zeitpunkt zu einem späteren zu „transportieren“: Die Speicherung als Inschrift. Die Herstellung von Inschriften mit Papier und Stift ist uns allen geläufig. Als es das noch nicht gab, benutzte man z. B. Felswände und Pinsel. Und seit einigen Jahrzehnten kann man auch magnetisierbare Schichten „beschriften“.
>   Aber was wird denn eigentlich gespeichert? Auf dem Papier stehen keine Schall- oder Lichtwellen oder andere Signale. Außerdem kann man verschiedene Inschriften herstellen, von denen Sie ganz selbstverständlich sagen würden, dass
>   „da die gleichen Zeichen stehen“.
>
> **Um sozusagen zum Kern dessen vorzustoßen „was da steht“, bedarf es eines Aktes in unseren Köpfen.** Den nennt man Abstraktion. [...]

---

In this case »der Akt« is »ein Vorgang«, meaning »an event, an action, something that happens«. And »bedürfen« is »to need something«. So »es bedarf eines Aktes« means: »an action is needed«.

The next sentence says what this action is: An abstraction.

You need the object to be in genitive case, because the word »bedürfen« needs a genitive object. »Bedürfen« can also come together with an accusative object, but this is considered to be old-fashioned and is rare (but still correct).

Comment: +1 für Ihre Antwort & auch für die "Grundbegriffe der Informatik" link! Ich will Informatik in Dt Uni studieren & wollte gerade nach solche [study materials ... Ressourcen? Gegenstände?] suchen. Perfekt! :) Danke.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the meaning of your example can just be given in a broad way, since the general context is not clear.

Nevertheless, this expression definitely relates to the *Akt* as a synonym for an action, a deed. In this context a *mental effort* might be another good way to describe the meaning of this sentence, the author wants to encourage you to start thinking.

The genitive is used because the verb *bedürfen* asks for a genitive-object. It's a fixed rule in german grammar, after *bedürfen* the genitive-object has to follow.

Comment: You forgot to add the meaning of *bedürfen*.